# Asking use to tag image before or after uploading : REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

In my react native application I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` for the user to upload some images and then using flatlist to display the images the user has uploaded. The code is provided for that:

```
const [imageList , setImageList] = useState([]);

const openCamera = (rateObj) => {        
     ImagePicker.openCamera({
         width: 300,
         height: 400,
         cropping: true,
       }).then(image => {
         onSelectedImage(image);
       });
}

const onSelectedImage = (image) => {
    let newImageList = imageList;
    const source = {uri: iamge.path};
    let imgItem = {
        id: Date.now(),
        url: source,
        content: image.data
    }
    newImageList.push(imgItem);
    setImageList(newImageList);
}
return(

<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => openCamera()}
> 
    <Text>Take a photo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity >
<FlatList 
    data={imageList}
    keyExtractor={(img) => img.id}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return(
             <Image style={myStyle} source={item.url} />
        )
    }}
/>
)
```

Now what I want to do is at some point of time, be it after the user has uploaded the image and can see the image, or while they are taking the image, the user should get an option kind of thing to mark this image as good or bad. I am not sure how I should approach this. And just to make myself more clear here, I am not looking for the user to first upload all the images and then displaying all the images to him and having radio buttons or something for each image to mark/tag it. If there is no other way then I guess I'll go ahead with this method but if someone can help me suggest a way to this?

Comment: You can show images to user then user, before upload them.

Answer (score 0):

I show you one of my recent components. i hope helps you:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro';
import {
  View,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import ActionSheet from 'react-native-action-sheet';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-viewing';

const BUTTONS = ['Gallery', 'Camera', 'Cancel'];

export default (props) => {
  let {files, setFiles} = props;
  const [ImageViwerIsVisible, showImageViwer] = useState(false);
  let [viewingIndex, setViewingIndex] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    viewingIndex !== -1 && showImageViwer(true);
  }, [viewingIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ImageViwerIsVisible && setViewingIndex(-1);
  }, [ImageViwerIsVisible]);

  const showActionSheet = () =>
    ActionSheet.showActionSheetWithOptions(
      {
        title: 'Choose photo location',
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: 2,
        destructiveButtonIndex: 2,
        tintColor: 'blue',
      },
      (buttonIndex) => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0:
            return selectFromGallery();
          case 1:
            return selectFromCamera();
          default:
            return 0;
        }
      },
    );

  const selectFromGallery = () =>
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      //cropping: true,
    })
      .then((image) => {
        setFiles([...files, image].flat());
      })
      .catch((e) => {});
  const selectFromCamera = () =>
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: true,
      includeExif: true,
    })
      .then((image) => {
        setFiles([...files, image]);
      })
      .catch((e) => {});
  return (
    <>
      <ImageViewer
        images={files.map((f) => ({uri: f.path}))}
        imageIndex={viewingIndex}
        visible={ImageViwerIsVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => showImageViwer(false)}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flex: 1,
          padding: 10,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showActionSheet()}>
          <Icon solid name="camera-retro" size={32} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ScrollView
          style={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse', flex: 1, marginLeft: 5}}
          horizontal>
          {files.map((file, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={file.path}
              onPress={() => setViewingIndex(index)}
              onLongPress={() =>
                ImagePicker.cleanSingle(file.path)
                  .then(() =>
                    setFiles(files.filter((f) => f.path !== file.path)),
                  )
                  .catch((e) => {})
              }
              style={{
                marginRight: 5,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: file.path}}
                style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 5}}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

I show images in a horizontal scroll view ( You can show them in your fav )
It is better to clean temporary images on `componentWillUnmount`, I forgot.